# Sharepoint Online REST: retrieving ServerRelativeUrl of deleted file?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

After using [getChanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn499819.aspx#bk_WebGetChanges) to get deleted files/folders, is there a way to get the deleted file's original ServerRelativeUrl (path) even if the file is not in the recycle bin (ex: it was directly deleted by the REST [DELETE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FileEndpoint) API)?

I tried `_api/web/getfilebyid(<unique-id>)` with the unique id in the `SP.ChangeFile` response, but it obviously fails because the file was deleted.

There was a `SP.ChangeItem` `DeleteObject` generated when deleting the file, but its `ServerRelativeUrl` is empty.

I found a similar question here, but the answer requires the file to be in the recycle bin:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25792930/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-the-meta-for-a-deleted-item-file-folder-for-office3